# the hyperspaces of homeomorphic metric spaces is homeomorphic

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I got a question asking whether the hyperspaces of homeomorphic metric spaces are homeomorphic or not. I think the answer should be yes, and I tried to prove my result. Say M and N are homeo, and let K(M) and K(N) denote their hyperspaces. Here, I use the Hausdorff metric D(A,B) = inf{r>0: $A\subset M_rB$ and $B\subset M_rA$}. I constructed the following homeomorphism: $g:K(M) \to K(N)$ with $g(U)=f(U)$, where $f$ is the homeomorphism between M and N. I can show that $g$ is a bijection. But how to show $g$ is continuous and its inverse is continuous? Actually, I tried show $g$ is continuous by showing it it preserves convergence, but I don't know how to show a seq of sets in K(N) converges.

Comment: What is the hyperspace of a metric space?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese The definition I have found is as follows: Given a metric space $(X,d)$, the associated hyperspace is $2^X$ with the topology induced by the Hausdorff metric $$d_H(A,B) = \max\left\{\sup_{x\in A}\inf_{y\in B}d(x,y),\ \sup_{y\in B}\inf_{x\in A} d(x,y) \right\} $$ for $A,B\subset X$. But I have not encountered this term before.

Comment: It's a metric when you restrict it to the set of compact sets in $(X, d)$. Not necessarily on the whole power set.

Comment: @AJY I meant to write that $(X,d)$ is assumed to be compact. Thanks for pointing that out.